# Alternative to Neoclipse

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am playing with neo4j to store some data with JAVA. I would like to have a good way to visualize my neo4j database and look through properties etc, mostly to have a feedback and understand what I put in my database.

I tried Neoclipse, but so far it is very buggy and often doesn't load the graph. Is there an alternative graph visualization program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is start the neo4j server and view your graph via the webAdmin: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tools-webadmin.html

Other options are the Gephi plugin for neo4j: https://gephi.org/plugins/neo4j-graph-database-support/
and there's a neo4j blog entry on GraphViz: http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/05/graph-this-rendering-your-graph-with.html

Comment: Gephi looks promising. In general, a very simple 'graph explorer' would be nice. Something that allows to quickly search for properties, inspect nodes etc.

Comment: maybe even http://console.neo4j.org useing D3.js could be interesting?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new solution to explore the content of a Neo4j graph database using a web browser called [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/).

It allows you to easily search and visualize nodes and edges.

You can see a [few alternative solutions](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize) on the Neo4j website.

These alternatives include :
- D3js : open-source library for visualization
- Gephi : a open-source project on graph visualization
- KeyLines : a JavaScript toolkit for visualizing networks

Disclaimer: I'm co-founder of Linkurious and Gephi.

Comment: FYI-The only option on linkurio.us right now is to sign up for an email list and wait for an invite to the beta.